# add web api endpoint, which return html from view

Tags: c#, web-api, asp.net-core, view, razor

I have ASP.NET 5 Web Api and need to do the following task:

Add endpoint, which get cshtml page and return generated html, so it should do the same what is does razor view engine.

What is better way to do this?

I added these views in this web api project and I think I can just make httpget request to view to get html response. Is it correct way?

So actually I need to covert ViewResult to ContentResult.

Comment: havent tested but surely you just add an mvc controller and return a view as normal?

Comment: @Ewan, I don't need to show view, just return html as string.

Comment: thats what webpages do

Comment: @Ewan, maybe you're right. Than I just need to replace `services.AddControllers()` to `services.AddControllersWithViews()` and create endpoint that returns this view.

Comment: if you want to return the string as an escaped json object then you can call the razor engine in code https://www.codemag.com/article/1312081/Rendering-ASP.NET-MVC-Razor-Views-to-String

Comment: but how to do the same in ASP.NET 5?